# how to create a sliding window and apply functions in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, window-functions, pandasql

I have the following dataframe :

```
Time      A

1         1
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         2
6         2
7         3
8         3
9         2
10        1
11        1
12        1
13        3
14        3
15        3
```

need to create a sliding window with length of 3 which slides 2 steps over time column and apply some costume function to column A  ( for the sake of this examplelet's say mean and max)

the r equivalent for it would be

```
 dat %>% dplyr::mutate(SMA_A=rollapplyr(A, 3, mean ,by = 2,align ="center", partial=TRUE, fill=NA),
                  Max_A =rollapplyr(A, 3, max ,by=2, align ="center", partial=TRUE,fill=NA)
                 )
```

expected output :

```
    Time  A     SMA_A    Max_A
      1   1    1.000000     1
      2   1       NA        NA
      3   1 1.000000        1
      4   1       NA        NA
      5   2 1.666667        2
      6   2       NA        NA
      7   3 2.666667         3
      8   3       NA        NA
      9   2 2.000000        3
      10  1       NA        NA
      11  1 1.000000        1
      12  1       NA        NA
      13  3 2.333333        3
      14  3       NA        NA
      15  3 3.000000        3
```

or without NAs

Comment: You want `df.set_index('Time').rolling(3)['A'].mean()`?

Comment: @Erfan - There is [`by = 2`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/rollapply) so it seems more complicated

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Comment: @Erfan made an edit to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Calculate rolling mean and max with [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)
2. Assign them as new columns
3. Get every 2nd index row by checking if the `remainder == 1` which means it's an uneven number
4. For every index in step3, assign `NaN` with [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df['A'] = df.rolling(3, center=True)['A'].mean().bfill().ffill()
df['Max_A'] = df.rolling(3, center=True)['A'].max().bfill().ffill()

mask_idx = df.index%2 == 1

df.loc[mask_idx, ['A', 'Max_A']] = np.NaN
```

**output**

```
    Time         A  Max_A
0      1  1.000000    1.0
1      2       NaN    NaN
2      3  1.000000    1.0
3      4       NaN    NaN
4      5  1.666667    2.0
5      6       NaN    NaN
6      7  2.666667    3.0
7      8       NaN    NaN
8      9  2.000000    3.0
9     10       NaN    NaN
10    11  1.000000    1.0
11    12       NaN    NaN
12    13  2.333333    3.0
13    14       NaN    NaN
14    15  3.000000    3.0
```